# Looping from the last row in one sheet to the first row in the next sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy/paste values from multiple sheets into one.

I have the loop down but the macro overwrites the values in the same column where the data is being written.

```
Sub Main()
    MedRT_EPC Sheets("Chemical Structure (14)")
    MedRT_EPC Sheets("Enzymes (19)")
    MedRT_EPC Sheets("Diuretics (5)")
    MedRT_EPC Sheets("Imaging Agents (12)")
    MedRT_EPC Sheets("Vitamins (27)")
End Sub


Sub MedRT_EPC(ws As Worksheet)

    ' Copy EPC cells Macro
    Dim bottomL As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    bottomL = ws.Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row: x = 1
 
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In ws.Range("I:I" & bottomI)
        If c.Value = "EPC" Then
            c.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("sheet4").Range("A" & x)
            x = x + 1
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

I've tried adding this:

```
    Dim LastTargetRow As Long
    ' code here
    With ws
        LastTargetRow = .Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End With
    ' code here
```

Comment: You might just need to change to `For Each c In ws.Range("I2:I" & bottomI)`. Use Long rather than Integer though as it handles more rows. `AutoFilter` would be quicker than looping

Comment: And I think that `bottomI` should be `bottomL` ? Get in the habit of using `Option Explicit`.

Comment: And another thing, don't reset `x` to 1 each time, find the last row in column A as per your other code. This one is the reason for your overwriting.

Comment: SJR - thank you for the comment; can you explain what you mean by reseting x to 1 each time? Also, changing ```For Each c In ws.Range("I2:I" & bottomI) ```doesn't seem to work for me. How would you suggest I use Autofilter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said above, `Autofilter` would be quicker (or using `Find`) but if you stick with a loop, the main thing is not to start each worksheet at row 1 for your paste range.

```
Sub MedRT_EPC(ws As Worksheet)

' Copy EPC cells Macro
Dim bottomL As Long, x As Long

bottomL = ws.Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim c As Range

For Each c In ws.Range("I2:I" & bottomL) 'or I1 as applicable
    If c.Value = "EPC" Then
        x = Worksheets("sheet4").Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        c.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("sheet4").Range("A" & x)
    End If
Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Doing this only pulls one row from the last worksheet I specified, rather than pulling all the rows with 'EPC'

Comment: Do you need to copy the whole row? Is there anything in column A of the rows you're copying?

Comment: I need to copy any cells in the sheet that have 'EPC' in column I; sometimes cells are in column B, sometimes in multiple columns. There would be multiple results from each sheet

Comment: I've made a change. If it doesn't work you'll have to do some debugging yourself and/or post a screenshot of your data.

Answer (score -1):

Your issue is that the "x" does not change. Try the below code. Fill the x1, x2, x3, x4, and x5 with the numbers you want.

```
   Sub Main()
        MedRT_EPC Sheets("Chemical Structure (14)",x1)
        MedRT_EPC Sheets("Enzymes (19)",x2)
        MedRT_EPC Sheets("Diuretics (5)",x3)
        MedRT_EPC Sheets("Imaging Agents (12)",x4)
        MedRT_EPC Sheets("Vitamins (27)"x5)
    End Sub
    Sub MedRT_EPC(ws As Worksheet, x as Integer)

' Copy EPC cells Macro
 Dim bottomL As Integer
 bottomL = ws.Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row: x = 1


 Dim c As Range
 For Each c In ws.Range("I:I" & bottomI)
 If c.Value = "EPC" Then
 c.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("sheet4").Range("A" & x)

 End If
 Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Khalid, thanks for the answer - running your code gives me a compile error with the first few lines, specifically with Sub Main() and Sheets. Not sure why, but it's not working

Comment: What error it gives? also I noticed one small typo. you see "x5" (last line in sub Main) there should be a comma before the x5

Comment: Yes I fixed that error. It's throwing 'Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment', highlighting ```Sub Main()``` as well as ```Sheets```

Comment: @KhalidSaifaldeen - you can edit your answer. However, although you diagnose the problem correctly I'm not sure your answer solves it?